# PDO binding error

Tags: php, pdo

I try to get some values from db

```
$client_ids = array('client_id' => $this->arParams['client_id']);
 print_r($client_ids);
 $client_ids_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($client_ids), '?'));
 $query = "SELECT odc.curr_id FROM office.dictionary_currency AS odc LEFT JOIN office.adwords_clients_google AS oacg ON odc.curr_code = oacg.client_currency WHERE oacg.client_id IN ($client_ids_in)";
        $google_currency = $this->DB->prepare($query);
        $google_currency->execute($client_ids);
        $google_currency->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $google_currency = $google_currency->fetch();
        $google_currency = $google_currency['curr_id'];
```

`$client_ids`looks like

```
Array
(
    [client_id] => 15087
)
```

`$query`

```
SELECT odc.curr_id FROM office.dictionary_currency AS odc LEFT JOIN office.adwords_clients_google AS oacg ON odc.curr_code = oacg.client_currency WHERE oacg.client_id IN (?)
```

and I get an error

```
PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /var/www/instruments/reports/report.php on line 531
```

it means,error in row

```
$google_currency = $this->DB->prepare($query);
```

What's wrong?How to fix it?

Comment: Added $query in post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code

```
 $client_ids = array('client_id' => $this->arParams['client_id']);
```

into something like

```
 $client_ids = array($this->arParams['client_id']);
```

So `$client_ids` is like

```
Array
(
   0 => 15087
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1):

If you use generic placeholders `?` you need to pass to execute a non-associative array. 
So you can either remove `'client_id'` key form your array, or use a named placeholder.

**Possible solution**

```
$client_ids = array($this->arParams['client_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!